# Co-worker and I have differing opinions. When launch is used a a noun, would it be, "at the launches conclusion," or at the launch's conclusion"

Tags: nouns, possessives

I'm losing my mind over this b/c I honestly have no clue if I am correct given that all of my coworkers are, honestly, much smarter than me. So, with that I want to change their spelling in this sentence:

> Do you agree to sharing all campaign results leveraging  within 60 days of the **launches conclusion**?

I believe it should be:

> Do you agree to sharing all campaign results leveraging  within 60 days of the **launch's conclusion**?

Please let me know your input as I feel crazy and dumb right now.

Comment: A simple dictionary check will tell you that launches is the plural noun. So was there a single launch or multiple launches?

Comment: Hi! I did check out the dictionary. But, I'm not looking for whether it is a plural or not. It is a single launch. Within the context of the sentence we're referring to the conclusion of the launch. So, say it was a book: It would be the "at the book's conclusion." And, so I am thinking as this is a single launch, and it is being used as a noun in this case it should be, "at the launch's conclusion." But, I just want to be sure.

Comment: Sorry, like I said, I feel dumb for even questioning, but I just want it to be confirmed.

Comment: Consider it confirmed by minds that are apparently greater than theirs when it comes to English genitives.  :-)

Comment: I'd go with **of launch end**, unless there's a requirement to use a longer word, conclusion.

Comment: You can also say "... within 60 days **of the conclusion of the launch**".  That may seem "a mouthful" with its repeated use of **of** but this kind of concatenation of phrases headed by **of** is perfectly idiomatic.

Answer (score 3):

> all of my coworkers are, honestly, much smarter than me

Not in all respects, apparently, since your version (with *launch's*) is obviously the correct one. Even if there were multiple launches involved, the correct form would be the possessive *launches'*, not the ordinary plural *launches.*

Comment: Please don't endorse questions obviously unsuitable for ELU. It encourages others.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth actually there's some meat in the question. We hear the *-es* in "launch's" which explains why the OP and their coworkers, who for all intents and purposes are native speakers, and therefore "experts" in their mother-tongue are confused. The answer is of course simple for anyone who has studied the basics of grammar but not every English-speaking person has.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Agreed. I think it's reasonable to ask a question whose answer seems obvious if the people around you are so confidently incorrect.

Comment: (I suspect that this is the sort of mistake that *only* native speakers would make; most EFL students would, I think, understand why the possessive is required here.)

Comment: @Mari-LouA Such questions belong on a site aimed at more basic questions: 'The answer is of course simple for anyone who has studied the basics of grammar.'  ELL has this function; it is possibly misnamed from a pragmatics point of view. ELU is aimed at linguists and proficient Anglophones.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth ELL is not for *easier* questions; it's for *non-native speakers.* I suspect that the asker in fact is a native speaker, just one confused by confidently incorrect coworkers. Questions that are most likely from non-natives should go to ELL, and ones whose answers that you can find in a dictionary should get closed. But "easiness" alone is not a valid close reason.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth ELL is not misnamed. It's people on ELU who use it as a dumping ground.

Comment: @alphabet If ELL is not open to native as well as native speakers, it is probably breaking some legal requirement. There are many native speakers who have more basic questions than are on-topic on ELU. Certainly the question here is too basic for a site aimed at linguists and proficient (not necessarily native-speaking) Anglophones.  '[Y]our version (with launch's) is obviously the correct one' and no doubt the opinion that this hardly needs supporting reference endorses this.